# Remove an empty style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove only empty style attribute?

For example if I add dynamically padding to an element:

```
$('div').css('padding', '10px');
<div style="padding:10px"></div>
```

Then I remove it with jQuery like

```
$('div').css('padding', '');
```

Looking at the firebug I end up with

```
<div style=""></div>
```

What I would like to do is remove style attribute only if does not contain any inline style.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with check style value:

```
if ($("div").attr("style") === "")
  $("div").removeAttr("style");
```

Hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method:

```js
if ($('div').attr('style') === '') {
  $('div').removeAttr('style')
}
```

```css
div:before {
  content: '<div> ';
}

div:after {
  content: ' </div>';
}

div:before,
div:after {
  font-style: Consolas;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #7D2727;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="">no style attribute</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to check for: when the style attribute is no there (`undefined`) or the `style` property is empty. I noticed jQuery methods `removeAttr()`, `removeProp()` did not work. I used DOM method `removeAttribute`

```js
$('p').each(function(i, e){
  
    var styleAttr = $(e).attr('style');

    if(!styleAttr || styleAttr == ''){
        
       e.removeAttribute('style'); // use DOM methods

    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p style="display:table;color:#ddd;">Test</p>
<p style="">Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[style=""]').forEach((el) => { 
   el.removeAttribute('style')
})
```

PS: Change `document` to any selector